# how to Deduct the Values of the Tables in access database via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

my Table1 is Stocks. i want to deduct the stocks because im making a simply Point of Sale system. My Stocks Table is ItemName, and Stock. im using Datagridview. is it possible to deduct the number of stocks in the database where the quantity is in the datagridview?

[image]

Stock - Quantity? (How to Code it?)

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not a tutorial site njor a code factory.

Comment: You have to show your coded attempt so we can help you.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting problems.  ExecuteScalar is for **returning** a value.  Use ExecuteNonQuery for Update and Insert queries, etc.